# How to update table after delete request in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am using "MDB" data table from "mdbootstrap" in my react project so I want to delete row after on click button. the user deleted from the server but the frontend still showing the row with the user I was Deleted But after I refresh the page the row is gone . the delete request sent successfully to the server. here is my code: set state does not solve the problem :

```
class Users extends Component {
notify = () => toast.warn(" User deleted Successfully !");

state = {
    users: [],
    tableRows: [],
}



async componentDidMount() {
    await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/admin/users', {
        headers: {
            'x-access-token': localStorage.getItem("token")
        }
    }
    )
        .then(response => response.data)

        .then(data => {

            this.setState({ users: data })

        })

        .then(() => {

            this.setState({ tableRows: this.getusers() })

        });

}

getusers = () => {
    let users = this.state.users.map((user) => {
        return (
            {
                id: user._id,
                name: user.name,
                cin: user.cin,
                delete: <MDBIcon
                    icon='trash'
                    className='red-text'
                    size='1x'
                    style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }}
                    onClick={() => this.handeldelete(user._id)}

                />,
                add: <Analys userId={user._id} />
            }
        )
    });

    return users;
}


handeldelete = async userId => {
    await axios.delete("http://localhost:3000/admin/users/" + userId, {
        headers: {
            'x-access-token': localStorage.getItem("token")
        }
    });
    const tableRow = this.state.tableRows;
    const userIndex = tableRow.findIndex(user => user.userId === userId); //It doesn't work

    tableRow.filter(1, userIndex);
    this.setState({ tableRows: tableRow });


};

render() {
    const data = {
        columns: [
            {
                label: 'USER ID',
                field: 'id',
                sort: 'asc',
                width: 150
            },
            {
                label: 'Name',
                field: 'name',
                sort: 'asc',
                width: 270
            },
            {
                label: 'CIN',
                field: 'cin',
                sort: 'asc',
                width: 200
            },
            {
                label: 'Delet',
                field: 'delete',
                sort: 'asc',
                width: 200
            },
            {
                label: 'ADD ANALYS',
                field: 'add',
                sort: 'asc',
                width: 200
            },
        ],
        rows: this.state.tableRows,



    };

    return (
        <div>
            <MDBDataTableV5 hover data={data} filter='name' proSelect searchTop searchBottom={false} />
            <ToastContainer />


        </div>

    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your delete function need a little rework. When you do the async axios delete call, you'll need to remove the data from your local state too.

```
handeldelete = async userId => {
    await axios.delete("http://localhost:3000/admin/users/" + userId, {
        headers: {
            'x-access-token': localStorage.getItem("token")
        }
    });
    this.setState((prev) => ({
      tableRows: prev.tableRows.filter(
        (row) => row.id !== userId
      )
    }));
};
```

I reproduce your app with fake data right here : https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-herschel-vwe2s?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you upvote and validate the answer please. Also, I think you should close the other question you asked few days ago :+1:

Answer (score 0):

const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([])

const removeData = (id) => {
let url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}`

```
axios.delete(url).then(res => {
    const del = employees.filter(employee => id !== employee.id)
    setEmployees(del)
})
```

}